# Почему при перезагрузки увеличивается ширина кнопки

Tags: css

При перезагрузке страницы на долю секунды увеличивается ширина кнопки. Почему это происходит? Как пофиксить?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Angulta/pen/yxazYK)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 30px;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), rgba(40, 180, 133, 0.8)), url('../img/hero.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%)
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.btn-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="heading-primary">
      <span class="heading-primary-main">Outdoors</span>
      <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where life happens</span>
    </h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Discover our tours</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Скорее всего шрифт прогружается.

Comment: У меня ничего не увеличивается, всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: подгружается шрифт, а до этого отображает системным. Замечаете из-за того, что транзишн стоит 0,2 секунды, без него было бы мгновенно.